# How can I modify the pivot choice for this quick sort algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, random, quicksort

I would like to modify the listed quick sort algorithm to choose the pivot choice as 1) A random element in the array. 2) The median of the first middle and last elements in the array.
====UPDATE====
Also how can I implement a timing mechanism to time the runtime for each algorithm?

```
void QuickSort1(long *L, int first, int last)
{
   int SplitPoint;  /* Value to Split list around */

   if( first < last )
   {
      /* Use first element as pivot (for splitting) */
      SplitPoint = first;                 /* assign SplitPoint to 1st index */
      Split(L, first, last, &SplitPoint); /* Split List around SplitPoint */
      QuickSort1(L, first, SplitPoint-1);  /* Sort 1st section of list */
      QuickSort1(L, SplitPoint+1, last);   /* Sort 2nd section of list */
   }
}

void Split(long *L, int first, int last, int *SplitPoint)
/* Splits a list around SplitPoint such that all values to the left of
   SplitPoint are < than SplitPoint and all values to the right of
   SplitPoint are >= SplitPoint */
{
   int x;            /* Key */
   int unknown;      /* index of unknown value */

   x = L[*SplitPoint];   /* assign x to value at SplitPoint */
   Swap( &L[*SplitPoint], &L[first] ); 
   *SplitPoint = first; 

   /* Loop walks through unknown portion of list */
   for ( unknown = first+1; unknown <= last; ++unknown)
   {
      /* If unknown value is < SplitPoint Value, then: */
#ifdef TAKE_COUNT
         comparison_count++;
#endif
      if( L[unknown] < x ) {
         ++ (*SplitPoint);                     /* SplitPoint is incremented */
         Swap( &L[*SplitPoint], &L[unknown] ); /* values are swapped*/
      }
   }
   /* Original value which was being split upon is swapped with the current
      SplitPoint to put it in correct position */
   Swap( &L[first], &L[*SplitPoint] );
}

int FindMedian(long *L, int A, int B, int C)
/* Receives array and three respective indices in the array. */
/* Returns the index of the median. */
{
   if (L[A] < L[B])
     if (L[B] < L[C])       /*  A < B < C  */
       return (B);
     else
       if (L[A] < L[C])         /*  A < C < B  */
     return (C);
       else
     return (A);            /*  C < A < B  */
   else
     if (L[A] < L[C])           /*  B < A < C  */
       return (A);
     else
       if (L[B] < L[C])     /*  B < C < A  */
     return (C);
       else
     return (B);            /*  C < B < A  */
}

void Swap(long *a, long *b)
/* This function uses call by reference to switch two elements.*/
{
   long temp;    /* temporary variable used to switch. */

   temp = *a;   /* temp = 1st # */
   *a = *b;     /* 1st # = 2nd # */
   *b = temp;   /* 2nd # = temp */
}
```

How am I able to modify this for the listed pivot choices.  They must also be added as additional menu options for the program.

Comment: You should add the tag for the programming language

Comment: The code has a comment that says where it chooses the pivot element. Make it choose a different one.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is that you always choose the first element in the array as the pivot point. If you wish to use another element, which is a very good idea if input is already sorted or (common case) mostly sorted with a few new elements appended, swap it with the first element. Now the pivot is the first element.

With that insight, the task should become very simple. To chose a random pivot, generate a random number of ) to N-1, and swap with the first element. To take a median of three, write a sightly messy but straightforwards set of if ... else statements.